# Creating a number array out of a text file on python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file-io, append

I want to create an array of numbers out of every line of a text file, The file contains numbers as follow:

```
11
9
7
12
```

This is the code i have to open the file and append the numbers to the array:

```
f = open('randomNumberx.txt','r')
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line.strip())
```

the code above gives me the following:

```
['11', '9', '7', '12' ]
```

and id like to have it as:

```
[11,9,7, 12]
```

i am using this for a sorting algorithm and when i have the numbers with the '' it makes my algorithm fail and if i use the array of numbers it works fine. any ideas?

Comment: Use `int`: `myList.append(int(line))`

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically, so `'2'> '100'` is `True`, that's why sort returns unexpected output.

Comment: `with open('randomNumberx.txt') as f: myList = map(int, f)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('randomNumberx.txt','r') as f:
    mylist = [int(x) for x in f]
```

You can also use `mylist = map(int, f)` as commented by @falsetru.

You should learn to use the `with` -statement. It's useful for many situations in python. For files, it handles the opening and closing of the file so you won't have to.

Read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: Itearting a file object yields lines. `readlines()` is not necessary. It will load all lines at once.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you don't need the `strip` call and no need to use `f.readlines()`, simply iterate over the file object.

Comment: `strip()` is not required. `int()` ignore spaces.

Comment: Pretty neat, this did it!